# How to nest a React component within itself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Condition from "./Condition";
import styled from "styled-components";

const SubinputForm = styled.form`
  text-align: left;
`;

const SubinputElementList = styled.li`
  text-align: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: inside;
`;

class Subinput extends Component {
  state = {
    isChild: false,
    type: "Text"
  };
  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  onClick = () => {
    this.setState({ isChild: true });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SubinputForm>
          <Condition typeOfInput={this.props.typeOfInput} />
          Question: <input />
          <br />
          Type:{" "}
          <select onChange={this.onChange} name="type" value={this.state.type}>
            <option>Text</option>
            <option>Number</option>
            <option>Yes / No</option>
          </select>
          <br />
          <br />
          <button onClick={this.onClick}>Add subinput</button>{" "}
          <button>Delete</button>
          <br />
        </SubinputForm>
        {this.state.isChild ? (
          <ul>
            <SubinputElementList>
              <Subinput typeOfInput={this.state.type} />
            </SubinputElementList>
          </ul>
        ) : (
          <ul>
            <SubinputElementList>Brak kolejnego subinputa</SubinputElementList>
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Subinput;
```

I nested the Subinput component within itself. So it's Subinput in Subinput, only if "isChild" is true (by default it is false). Why is it not working? I have no error, and when I change isChild to true (by button), the child appears for literally 0.5 sec and then disappears. I don't know why.

[GitHub Project](https://github.com/windsmasher/JS-Coding-Challenge)

Comment: Did you just assume the React component's gender?

Comment: Recursive components are bad design imo. There's hardly any real reason to do it, but if you do it, you need to ensure you don't create an infinite render loop. You'll likely need a condition within the component to ensure it stops at a particular point.

Comment: problem solved. event.preventDefault() in onClick function.